# Eclipse Luna, can't UPDATE TO HEAD

Tags: eclipse

I recently installed Eclipse Luna, when I right click on my `FORCE.COM` project, I can no longer find the option to `UPDATE TO HEAD`.

Am I missing a plugin or some configuration step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UPDATE TO HEAD` is related to some version control plugin

for **git**:

- [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/)

for **svn**:

- [subversive](http://eclipse.org/subversive/)
- [subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)